# Stabilizing online average calculation

Tags: numerical-analysis, error-estimation, floating-point

In Knuth, the following method for computing an average is presented:
\begin{align*}
M_{n} = M_{n-1} + (x_{n} - M_{n-1})/n
\end{align*}
(See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), if you don't have TAOCP.)

Assuming the samples all lie a bounded distance away from the average, then as $n \to \infty$, $(M_{n-1}-x_n)/n$ becomes very small, and eventually $M_{n-1} \oplus (x_{n}\ominus M_{n-1}) \oslash n$ becomes bitwise equal to $M_{n-1}$. The average computed by this formula then stops evolving in response to new data.

What are the known techniques to avoid this?

*Update*: I believe that this scheme has error $|\hat{M}_n -M_{n}| \le n\mu_{M} \underline{M}_{n}$, where
\begin{align*}
\underline{M}_{n} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |x_{i}|,
\end{align*}
and $\mu_{M}$ is the unit roundoff, but I couldn't prove it. This won't directly answer the question, but might put me on the track to get improvements. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a lot of data then the averge does NOT change by much when you add more. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't change at all, not that it doesn't change much.

Comment: Example: Float precision, after 10^7 data points, no change to average unless there's a huge outlier. If there are 10^9 data points (totally reasonable), it's stuck after 10^7, and the average is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: The mean of a random sample of 10^7 points from a population of 10^9 points is likely to be a very good estimate of the population mean.  What we don't know from the question posed is how 'good' a random sample the first 10^7 points represent.

Comment: I should clarify: The first 10^7 samples are not assumed to be random nor somehow representative of the entire population.